# Query only most recent value if duplicates exist

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-forms, inventory, google-sheets-query

I work at a warehouse and I am developing an Inventory System. When products come in, it is because they are damaged. I have one person fill out a row in Google Sheets when the product arrives (**Sheet1** in the workbook link below). I mainly need Barcode, Issue, and Date from this Sheet).

Next, a mechanic fixes the product and fills out a google form with his name and the barcode of the product; the responses are **Form Responses 1** in the workbook link below.

I then pull the data for all the incoming products from **Sheet1** to a new tab (**Barcodes In/Out** in the workbook link below), querying Barcode, Issue, and Date. I pull the data for all the outgoing product in another column in this tab, querying the Barcode from the **Form Responses 1**. Column E (Backlog) has a formula that only shows barcodes of products that have not been repaired (gone "out").

I pull the data for what is in my Back log (products still in warehouse needing repair) into another tab named **Back Log**. This was working perfectly until I realized ***products can come back to our warehouse*** (i.e. "123" can come in and get fixed and sent out again. "123" can come back again for more repairs.)

This poses a problem because **Back Log** now shows "123" twice with two different Issues.

I need **Back Log** to query "123" only and only with the most recent Issue.

This is a lot of info, but I tried to be as detailed as I could. Thank you for your help in advance!

[Here is the link to my workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IB7uCWEhWcYBKq7kqzOYrity7wvPHsTai9hmbRDrUuo/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In G2 I entered

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(Sheet1!B2:B), sort({Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet1!A2:F}, 7, 0), {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0)))
```

UPDATE: Based on new info...

```
=query(ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(unique(Sheet1!B2:B), sort(filter({Sheet1!B2:B, Sheet1!A2:F}, not(regexmatch(Sheet1!B2:B&"", textjoin("|", 1, filter('Barcodes In/Out'!D2:D, isna(match('Barcodes In/Out'!D2:D, 'Barcodes In/Out'!E2:E, 0))))))), 7, 0), {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 0))), "where Col1 <>''")
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: You're helping me on Google Docs Help Forum as well aren't you? Haha. 

I added some more mock data, this time to the Form Responses 1 Tab. If you look at Barcodes In/Out tab, the Backlog Column only includes "123" and "789" which is correct. The formula you provided does not exclude Barcodes that appear on Out Column(in this case "456") on Barcodes In/Out like I'd like it to.